# Once logged in /login should redirect to home page

Tags: angular, angular8

Problem:

Once user logged in successfully, it navigates to home page. Again if user tries /login on url, then it navigates back to login page. If already logged in then it should navigates to home page instead of login page. How can I achieve this.

This is my routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
   { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
 ];
```

Auth guard service.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;

        console.log("current User 2:"+currentUser);

        if (currentUser) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Guard your login page that checks if the user is already logged in. If he is, simply return false from that guard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can guard your login page like this:

Guard:

```
constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService){}
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        return !this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn();
    }
```

Routing Module:

```
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] }
```